# Using one module inside another in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make some code a bit more modular in Python and am running into one issue which I'm sure is straight forward but I can't seem to see what the problem is.

Suppose I have a script, say MyScript.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import myFunction as mF

data_frame = mF.data_imp()

print(data_frame)
```

where myFunction.py contains the following:

```
def data_imp():
    return pd.read_table('myFile.txt', header = None, names = ['column'])
```

Running MyScript.py in the command line yields the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MyScript.py", line 5, in <module>
        data_frame = mF.data_imp()
      File "/Users/tomack/Documents/python/StackQpd/myFunction.py", line 2, in data_imp
        return pd.read_table('myFile.txt', header = None, names = ['column'])
    NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: use `import pandas as pd` inside `myFunction` module.

Comment: You should import pandas in your myFunction script

Comment: Thanks, so another question would be, suppose I had a set of python files - myFunction1.py, myFunction2.py, myFunction3.py - each containing functions that use 'read_table' from pandas and are called in MyScript.py, how can I minimise the number of times I type 'import pandas as pd'?

Answer (score 3):

You need to import pandas in your function or script myFunction:

```
def data_imp():
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.read_table('myFile.txt', header = None, names = ['column'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers here are right, because your module indeed lacks `myFunction` import.

If stated more broad this question can also contain following: in case of circular import the only 2 remedies are:

1. `import pandas as pd , but not from pandas import something`
2. Use imports right there in functions you need in-placd